# How to add up each count in defaultdict?

Tags: python

This is what I have to count each word in a document:

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_dict=defaultdict(int)

def count_words(newstring):
    words=newstring.lower().split()
    for word in words:
        word_dict[word]+=1
```

When I print `word_dict`, I got the following results:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'rate': 1, 'babo-free': 1, 'risk': 3, 'interest': 1})
```

I need to add each count so that `total_count` variable should be equal to 6.

I guess this may be too easy for many of you guys, but as a beginner, I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your object shouldn't be a defaultdict, it really ought to be a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).  You're importing from `collections` anyway, and this way, you can do any number of operations on your `Counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `iteritems` you can get a list of key value pairs. With that you can use a for loop to sum the numbers together.

Eg

```
sum = 0
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    sum += v
```

Comment: 2 comments,  first, since you don't use `k`, you're better off using `d.values()` or `d.itervalues()` instead of `d.iteritems()`.  Second, rather than summing explicitly, use the builtin `sum` function.  :)

Comment: I avoided both those things because it's a beginner question, could've added it as improvements though =)

Answer (score 10):

You can do this the same way you would any dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
>>> sum(d.values())
9
```

In Python 2.* you could also use

```
>>> sum(d.itervalues())
9
```

which doesn't create a new list, but frankly it's unlikely your lists are long enough for this to be a bottleneck.  And the `defaultdict` works the same way:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d2 = defaultdict(int)
>>> d2.update(d)
>>> d2
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 1, 'd': 4})
>>> sum(d2.values())
9
```

Incidentally, in Python 2.7+, there's also a handy `Counter` object:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("a b A B B c".lower().split())
Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 2, 'c': 1})
>>> Counter("a b A B B c".lower().split()).most_common()
[('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
>>> sum(Counter("a b A B B c".lower().split()).values())
6
```